# SPOJ ROOTCIPH wrong answer

Tags: c

Here is the [SPOJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPOJ) problem [ROOTCIPH](http://www.spoj.com/problems/ROOTCIPH/).

I have solved it by two ways in C. One approach gives the correct answer and the other is wrong.

We won’t discuss the how to solve the problem. The solution is simple. It is always a*a -2*b. (Think in term of roots of a cubic equation...) Anyway, the question does not relate to it. This detail I gave so that one can run their solution to the source and analyse more.

Now the question:

In the code below, if instead of 'int', I  take long long, my answer is shown correct, otherwise for 'int' it is shown wrong. I have taken %lld in printf, so even if the integer bound exceeds, it should  handle.

Wrong code:

```
int main()
{
    int a, b, c;
    int t;

    scanf("%d", &t);

    while(t--)
    {
        scanf("%d%d%d", &a, &b, &c);
        printf("%lld\n", 1LL*a*a - 2*1LL*b);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Right code:

```
int main()
{
    long long a, b, c;
    int t;

    scanf("%d", &t);

    while(t--)
    {
        scanf("%lld%lld%lld", &a, &b, &c);
        printf("%lld\n", a*a - 2*b);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note that absolute value of a, b, and c will not exceed 10^8.

Why does the first approach give the wrong solution? You can run the solution in the link given and check.

According to [C operator precedence table](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm) , `*` have left to right associativity.

Comment: Is it possible that there are very large numbers that don't fit in an `int` that do fit into `long`?

Comment: i have used 1LL , so by order of precedence , the resultant answer should always be long long

Comment: The result will be a `long long`; that says nothing about the types of intermediate values (in particular, a*a).

Comment: What happens if you replace the printf expression in wrong code with (1LL*a)*a-2*(1LL*b)?

Answer (score 1):

As [Engineer2021 suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22199793/spoj-rootciph-wrong-answer#comment33700542_22199793), using `long long`'s, which can hold bigger numbers than `int`'s, is likely the difference.  For example, part of your expression is `a*a`; even if you multiply that by a `1LL`, in effect converting it, the damage may have already been done.

Comment: But the multiplication by `1LL` happens before the multiplication `a*a`.

Comment: Just because you put it first doesn't (necessarily) enforce the order of execution.  Compilers are clever beasts...

Comment: It does enforce the order. Compilers have to conform to the standard, which specifies the order.

Comment: Unless I'm mis-reading it, this says otherwise: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/eval_order

Comment: Your link says "the expression a + b + c is parsed as (a + b) + c due to left-to-right associativity of operator+". The same is true for multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

If your answer is not in the interval [-2 147 483 648 ; 2 147 483 647], then it can't fit into an int, which is stored in 32 bits (or 16 if you are on a 16 bits system, so in [-32 768 ; 32 767]).

A long long integer is stored in 64 bits, regardless of your system.

Comment: +1 for noting about 16-bit.  Note: A long long integer is stored on _at least_ 64 bits.

Comment: From *[What range of values can integer types store in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1819236)*: *"The* ***minimum*** *range for this type, if your compiler supports it, is: long long int: -9,223,372,036,854,775,807 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807. unsigned long long int: 0 to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615."*