# count the digits of a number with recursion

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

bool recursion(int numb, int k, int br)
{
    if(br==1) return (numb==k);
    return k==(numb%10) || recursion(numb/10,k,br-1);

}

int main(){
    int num,n;
    cin>>num;
    n=num;
    int p;
    cin>>p;
    int br=1;
    while(n>10){
        n=n/10;
        br++;
    }
    cout<<br<<endl;
    cout<<recursion(num,p,br);
    return 0;
}
```

This is the whole program for counting the digits of a number , but it doesn't work for numbers with more than 10 digits. Does anybody know why?

Comment: Check out `INT_MAX` from `<limits.h>`.

Comment: Try `long long` instead of `int` if you have a supporting ocmpiler.

Comment: Try indenting the code

Comment: there is a limit to (int) please see this answer 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819189/what-range-of-values-can-integer-types-store-in-c

Answer (score 1):

First, your recursive program is not counting the digits in a number, it checks if a particular digit `k` is present within the last `br` digits of the number `numb`.

It does not work for numbers with more than ten digits because the largest number on your system that `int` can represent has ten digits. On 32-bit systems it is `2,147,483,647`.

To make it work with more digits, use a larger data type - say, `long long`, or `uint64_t`.

Answer (score 0):

On a 32-bits machine, integers are 32 bits long. The largest signed integer you can get is `2^31 - 1 = 2147483647` which has 10 digits. You've got to use strings to allow for arbitrarily large numbers.

Comment: no they aren't necessary. The length of `int` is implementation defined. For example, on my 64 bit machine, `int`s are also 32 bit.