# long long value in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, long-long

We know that -2*4^31 + 1 = -9.223.372.036.854.775.807, the lowest value you can store in long long, as being said here: [What range of values can integer types store in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819189/what-range-of-values-can-integer-types-store-in-c).
So I have this operation:

```
#include <iostream>

unsigned long long pow(unsigned a, unsigned b) { 
    unsigned long long p = 1; 
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < b; i++) 
        p *= a; 
    return p; 
}

int main()
{
    long long nr =  -pow(4, 31) + 5 -pow(4,31);
    std::cout << nr << std::endl;
}
```

Why does it show -9.223.372.036.854.775.808 instead of -9.223.372.036.854.775.803? I'm using Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130291/discussion-on-question-by-peter-long-long-value-in-visual-studio).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a really nasty little problem which has three(!) causes.

Firstly there is a problem that floating point arithmetic is approximate.  If the compiler picks a `pow` function returning float or double, then 4**31 is so large that 5 is less than 1ULP (unit of least precision), so adding it will do nothing (in other words, 4.0**31+5 == 4.0**31).  Multiplying by -2 can be done without loss, and the result can be stored in a `long long` without loss as the wrong answer: -9.223.372.036.854.775.808.

Secondly, a standard header *may* include other standard headers, but is not required to.  Evidently, Visual Studio's version of `<iostream>` includes `<math.h>` (which declares `pow` in the global namespace), but Code::Blocks' version doesn't.

Thirdly, the OP's `pow` function is not selected because he passes arguments `4`, and `31`, which are both of type `int`, and the declared function has arguments of type `unsigned`.  Since C++11, there are lots of overloads (or a function template) of [`std::pow`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow).  These all return `float` or `double` (unless one of the arguments is of type `long double` - which doesn't apply here).

Thus an overload of `std::pow` will be a better match ... with a double return values, and we get floating point rounding.

Moral of the story: Don't write functions with the same name as standard library functions, unless you *really* know what you are doing!

Comment: "Visual Studio includes" should read "the version of `<iostream>` shipped with Visual Studio includes"

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio has defined `pow(double, int)`, which only requires a conversion of one argument, whereas your `pow(unsigned, unsigned)` requires conversion of both arguments unless you use `pow(4U, 31U)`. Overloading resolution in C++ is based on the inputs - not the result type.

Comment: In addition, including <iostream> *may* (but is not required to) declare the standard version of `pow`.  I suspect the problem is that it does on VS, and doesn't on Code:Blocks.

Answer (score 2):

The lowest long long value can be obtained through [numeric_limits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits). For long long it is:

```
auto lowest_ll = std::numeric_limits<long long>::lowest();
```

which results in:

> -9223372036854775808

The `pow()` function that gets called is not yours hence the observed results. Change the name of the function.

Comment: Please see the comments under the question. He has also tried self made unsigned long long function.

Answer (score 2):

The only possible explaination for the -9.223.372.036.854.775.808 result is the use of the `pow` function from the standard library returning a double value. In that case, the `5` will be below the precision of the double computation, and the result will be exactly -2<sup>63</sup> and converted to a long long will give `0x8000000000000000` or `-9.223.372.036.854.775.808`.

If you use you function returning an unsigned long long, you get a warning saying that you apply unary minus to an unsigned type and still get an ULL. So the whole operation should be executed as unsigned long long and should give without overflow `0x8000000000000005` as unsigned value. When you cast it to a signed value, the result is undefined, but all compilers I know simply use the signed integer with same representation which is `-9.223.372.036.854.775.803`.

But it would be simple to make the computation as signed long long without any warning by just using:

```
long long nr =  -1 * pow(4, 31) + 5 - pow(4,31);
```

As a addition, you have neither undefined cast nor overflow here so the result is perfectly defined per standard provided unsigned long long is at least 64 bits.

Answer (score 1):

Your first call to `pow` is using the C standard library's function, which operates on floating points.  Try giving your `pow` function a unique name:

```
unsigned long long my_pow(unsigned a, unsigned b) {
    unsigned long long p = 1;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < b; i++)
        p *= a;
    return p;
}

int main()
{
    long long nr = -my_pow(4, 31) + 5 - my_pow(4, 31);
    std::cout << nr << std::endl;
}
```

This code reports an error: "unary minus operator applied to unsigned type, result still unsigned".  So, essentially, your original code called a floating point function, negated the value, applied some integer arithmetic to it, for which it did not have enough precision to give the answer you were looking for (at 19 digits of presicion!).  To get the answer you're looking for, change the signature to:

```
long long my_pow(unsigned a, unsigned b);
```

This worked for me in MSVC++ 2013.  As stated in other answers, you're getting the floating-point `pow` because your function expects `unsigned`, and receives signed integer constants.  Adding `U` to your integers invokes your version of `pow`.

Comment: "unary minus operator applied to unsigned type, result still unsigned" is NOT an error.

Comment: Take it up with MSVC. :)  I didn't have any special compilation flags set.