# why is the garbage value for an integer so un-integerly huge

Tags: c++

Today while experimenting with a C++ program i tried to get a random variable from a garbage value with code that read

```
int main(){
    int x,r;
    r = x%7
    cout << r;
}
```

needless to say this method didn't work since x was being used without initialization however when I looked at he variable watch I saw that the garbage value of x was -846.... and the same value for r. This confused me as to how could an integer hold such insanely huge garbage values. Normally C++ integers are ±32676 however the insane 7+ digit value I saw was never in this range. What could be the reason for this very large value if integers can hold only small values

Comment: No, the `sizeof`  an `int` is implementation specific. On Linux/x86 systems (both 32 and 64 bits) it is 4 bytes so 32 bits. Today only very few systems have 16 bits `int` (mostly embedded things à la [Arduino](https://www.arduino.cc/)...)

Comment: actually size of 'int' is defined as 32 bits, no matter what. If you need 16, it will be 'short int';

Comment: print [`INT_MAX`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits) and see

Comment: @Serge: are you sure of that? It depends upon the C++ standard

Comment: "why is the garbage value for an integer so un-integerly huge" - it may be small or large, 32bit or 64bit or pigs may fly. Point is; it is *undefined* - you can't use/read it and *if* you do, then your entire program is undefined.

Comment: @Serge No, the size of int depends on implementation. 16 bits would be quite typical on 16 bit systems.

Comment: @Serge there are a lot of platforms where [`int` has 16, 18, 24, 36 bits...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2098149/995714) The only requirement is that [`INT_MAX` must be at least 32767](https://stackoverflow.com/q/589575/995714)

Comment: ok, ok,,,, i was wrong :-(. It only defines that 'int' should accommodate INT_MAX, where the latter could be platform dependent. Here is a nice overview of it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589575/what-does-the-c-standard-state-the-size-of-int-long-type-to-be. So, as Luu suggested, find out the value of INT_MAX/MIN in your system.

Comment: Part way down this page (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) is a chart listing the minimum sizes of integer data types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1819236/6525260), the *minimum* (emphasis mine) ranges of an integer is -32,767 to 32,767. The actual limits are implementation defined, and are most likely from -2 billion to positive 2 billion.

To check the integer limits on your device, you could use the header [`<limits>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) as follows:

```
int imin = std::numeric_limits<int>::min(); // minimum value
int imax = std::numeric_limits<int>::max(); //or INT_MAX
```

Answer (score 1):

> Normally C++ integers are ±32676

This is false on most systems (except embedded things like [Arduino](http://arduino.cc)). On most current C++ systems, `int` uses 32 bits. IIRC the standard mandates *at least* 16 bits.

You should use the [`<limits>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/limits) standard [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) (or better) header.

BTW your program is a typical example of [**undefined behaviour**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) so you need to be [*very scared*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108) (and you should not *expect* any particular concrete behavior).

Answer (score 0):

Integers are ussually at least 32bit on most architectures you are likely to use.
So can hold  around +/-2 billion

Answer (score 0):

Integer size is usually 4 bytes on most operating systems (platforms). Therefore, at the lowest, which is 32-bit architectures, it can hold values from (-2147483648) to (+2147483648).
If you're working with a 64-bit architecutre, which is the common one today, you can hold values from (-2^64 / 2) to (+2^64 / 2).

Take a look at this link that shows the size of integer on different platforms: http://ivbel.blogspot.co.il/2012/02/size-of-primitive-types-in-c-language.html

Comment: Even ob most 64 bit architectures int is a 32bit type.